# remove %20 in url with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

i want to remove the %20 in my url

i use react-router-dom and my route is configure like that

`<Route path="/guide/:name/:id" component={pro}/>`

if my url is "/guide/test of url/1" 
my url will be /guide/test%20of%20url/1

how can i remove the %20?

if i do `<Route path="/guide/test of url/1" component={pro}/>`
my url will be /guide/test of url/1

i aslo trie to use urldecoding without result success

thanks

Comment: `%20` is url-encoded space character  it is gonna be there if you use space in your url. you can, use `-` over space: `<Route path="/guide/test-of-url/1" component={pro}/>`

Comment: yeah but i generate the url dynamicly from an api i could creat a funtion to replace space by - but i want to know if there is a solution to avoid that

Comment: no you can not check the specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1 <-- they use `space` as an example